# Keep local folder in sync with Samba share

Tags: linux, rsync, samba

I have a local folder on my Linux Mint desktop (my Dropbox folder, though that shouldn't matter), and I'd like to keep it synced with my school's "datastore" Samba share, which I can connect to from that desktop. What's the best way to make sure changes made from either end are updated in both places? Should I keep it mounted through Nautilus and use symlinks? Would `rsync` and `smbclient` be a better combination? Is there some other tool I should look into?